# Azure Event Hub: Unknown outgoing messages in resource metrics

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We've just started using a new Azure Event Hub resource with a pretty basic setup. There are two hub instances, sending and receiving to and from these instances is done by a Logic App, Stream Analytics and an Azure Function every two hours. From the metrics section within the Azure portal I get the following diagram:

[image: Event Hub Metrics]

I can explain the light blue and purple peaks happening every two hours. But does anyone have an idea about the four messages going out once an hour? Drilling into the metrics I can see that it's actually two messages per hub instance. Unfortunately I have not yet found a way to identify these messages. Is this maybe an internal technical thing? And if so:

1. Can I ignore these messages?
2. Can I still find the message content anywhere within the Azure portal or Service Bus Explorer?

Thanks in advance, Tobi

**UPDATE:** Things have slightly changed, there are now multiple occurrences of unidentified outgoing messages per hour:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** Sorry for the confusion, it's still the same amount of unknown messages (4 in total, 2 per hub instance); they*re just not processed at the same time anymore.

Comment: Hi! Have you done anything with it?

Comment: Sorry, I can‘t remember what happened regarding this issue and don‘t have access to the Azure resources anymore

Answer (score 0):

in order to identify these messages, I will recommend to:

1. Add an additional output to blob storage in this Stream Analytics job
2. Add another step in the same job outputting all messages to this new output: e.g. SELECT * INTO newoutput FROM input

Then, restart the job Using storage explorer you can have a look at these messages.

Let me know how it goes.

Thanks,

JS

Comment: Thanks for the support. Would it really help to create a new input for the same event hub instance I already have an input for? This is what I do within my SA query `SELECT * INTO [My-Blob-Output] FROM [My-Input]` with `[My-Input]` pointing to the relevant event hub instance. The mysterious messages are not processed by this query; neither are they displayed as input events nor are they stored within the configured blob container.

Comment: If you don't see anything in the blob storage, it may be because the format of the incoming message is not supported. ASA supports only JSON, AVRO and CSV at this time. In this case you will see some error reported in the activity logs.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Unfortunately, activity logs don't show me any data right now, which is rather odd. But since I heard about a global (or maybe regional?) problem with activity logs of many resources of all types yesterday, I'll try again every few hours.